# How to label clustered groups in a vector?

Tags: r

Data:

```
set.seed (112098)
op <- data.frame(id=1:100,cluster=rbinom(100,1,0.5))

id cluster
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 0
5 1
6 1
7 0 
8 0
9 1
```

Intended:

```
id cluster groups
1 1 1
2 1 1
3 1 1
4 0 0
5 1 2
6 1 2
7 0 0
8 0 0
9 1 3
```

Essentially, every consecutive `1` series forms a group. How could I add the group column in R?

Comment: are the clusters always padded by 0s? `rl <- rle(op$cluster); rl$values <- cumsum(rl$values) * rl$values; op$groups <- inverse.rle(rl)`

Comment: @rawr Yes, they are. I really like your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option using `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(op)[, groups := rleid(cluster)*(cluster)
         ][groups!=0, groups := as.integer(factor(groups))]
head(op, 9)
#    id cluster groups
#1:  1       1      1
#2:  2       1      1
#3:  3       1      1
#4:  4       0      0
#5:  5       0      0
#6:  6       1      2
#7:  7       1      2
#8:  8       0      0
#9:  9       1      3
```